# Qual o significado de ようで e ような na seguinte frase? | What is the meaning of ようで and ような in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, nuances, verbs

Estou analisando a letra de uma música chamada  君が好きだと叫びたい. Cheguei em um ponto de dúvida na frase  **恋をしているようで 躍らされてるような**.

1. Mais especificamente eu gostaria de entender o conceito por traz de  **ようで**, o que ele significa nessa frase?
2. Qual o significado de **ような**  nessa frase?
3. E quanto ao verbo　**踊らされてる**, ele está na forma passiva?

> ざわめいたフロアに にぎわうテーブル越し
> なにげない 君の視線に酔いしれ
> 恋をしているようで 躍らされてるような
> 高鳴る鼓動に もううそはつけない ([context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Ow1XED9zE&t=3s))

---

I'm analyzing the lyrics of a music called 君が好きだと叫びたい. I have doubts regarding the phrase **恋をしているようで 躍らされてるような**.

1. To be more specific, I would like to know the meaning of **ようで**.
2. What does **ような** mean in that phrase?
3. As for the verb **踊らされてる**, is it in passive form?

> ざわめいたフロアに にぎわうテーブル越し
> なにげない 君の視線に酔いしれ
> 恋をしているようで 躍らされてるような
> 高鳴る鼓動に もううそはつけない ([context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Ow1XED9zE&t=3s))

Comment: Do you understand how ようだ or ようです works?

Comment: @aguijonazo I've submitted a translation. I think it's good enough for a *quick* translation.

Comment: Você se refere a esse 様です?
Se for o caso, pelas minhas pesquisas seria algo como "Parece ser"

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of ようだ is correct. It does mean something like “parece ser.”

ようで and ような are both derived from ようだ. The former is the conjunctive form whereas the latter modifies a noun like a な-adjective. In this case, 恋をしているよう and 躍らされてるよう are connected by で and they both modify 鼓動, which is also modified by 高鳴る.

踊らされてる is the result of the following series of transformations.

1. The core verb is 踊る.
2. 踊らす is one of the causative forms of 踊る, meaning “to make someone dance.” (The other is 踊らせる.)
3. 踊らされる is the passive form of 踊らす, and therefore, one of the causative-passive forms of 踊る, meaning “to be made to dance.” (The other is 踊らせられる.)
4. 踊らされている is the continuous/progressive form of 踊らされる.
5. 踊らされてる is a colloquial, contracted form of 踊らされている.

So, the heart beats are such that it seems like you are in love and at the same time you are being made to dance.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado por dispor um minuto de seu tempo para me ajudar. Acho que agora faz mais sentido.